# Use DropBox Cloud storage from Linux file system

Tags: linux, dropbox, cloud-storage

Anybody know how to use DropBox cloud storage from the Linux file system (that is, access the files through the file system without storing them locally, as opposed to the normal method of storing a local copy and synchronizing it)? I can find a Windows Shell extension project for DropBox. How about Linux?
Or, do you know any other Cloud storage solution which allows mounting as Linux file system.

I want to use my Cloud storage from Linux as like normal files in local HDD without any web user interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found one solution. FUSE is my option to consider.
By using it, I think I can implement user level file system for DropBox.

In fact, it's already support file system for Box.net Cloud Storage.
Please check about this :

http://code.google.com/p/boxfs/

Comment: That is nice, but just so you know, it's completely unnecessary. Dropbox does not mount; it syncs. Install the Linux client for Dropbox and tell it what folder you want to sync, and changes made locally are synced remotely. This is done asynchronously and automatically, with absolutely no user intervention required as long as the client is active.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I wanted to use Cloud based storage from the embedded device which has Linux O.S. and FUSE was good solution to achieve my goal. I think my question was too obscure.

Comment: Drop box requires X to install. On a headless embedded device, your solution is better. Next time you should be mire clear about what makes your needs unique to improve the quality of your answers.

Comment: There is (now) a Dropbox daemon that can run on a headless server. I've used it and it's pretty slick. https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx

Comment: There appear to be multiple solutions using Fuse, but none of them actually seems good. One of the ones I found was vaporware, one stored passwords in plaintext, and one (DropFuse) attempted to cache all the files, making it useless if the point is to not use the disk.

Comment: @DanielH You're right. In fact, I wrote my own C codes by using FUSE to remove caching and dependancy to runtime such as Python.

Comment: I would like this too; could you share this somewhere?

Comment: Let me try arrange it and I'll let you know. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox doesn't "mount", it just synchronizes, like `rsync`.  Mounting requires a whole host of additional operations, such as locking and random access, which I doubt have support from the Dropbox server.